# Application.advise() ComException in JNA

Tags: excel, com, jna, office-automation, comexception

I'm handling Excel in Java.
We are accessing Excel application data using JNA's COM API.
I want to hook up when the Excel application closes.
So, I'm using a JNA-based library.

`your text`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.Factory
`your text`eu.doppel_helix.jna.tlb.excel1.AppEventsListenerHandler
`your text`eu.doppel_helix.jna.tlb.excel1.Application
...

However, when registering an event handler in Application.advise(), it is blocked, so if you do it with threads, the error will occur as shown below.

Exception in thread "Thread-1" com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: advise: Interface must define a value for either iid via the ComInterface annotation
`at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.ProxyObject.advise(ProxyObject.java:287) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)`
...

What should I do to prevent the above exception from occurring?
Fundamentally, how do I catch an event where the Excel application that I ran closes?
Please help me.
I don't have Windows COM operation method and API knowledge.

Thank you.

I did below :

`Factory factory = new Factory( myComThread ); Application excelApp= factory.createObject(Application.class); excelApp.advise(Application.class, new MyAppEventListenerHandler()); //no response. blocking`

I expected when Excep application is closing I can catch that event.

Comment: The exception is very clear in its message: you need an IID for the object. This is how Windows knows what COM object you are referring to.  What is "your text" in your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [Application.WorkbookBeforeClose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookbeforeclose) event which is fired immediately before any open workbook closes. If there is a single workbook opened the Excel Application instance can be closed with it.

Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you deal with open XML documents only you may consider using the Open XML SDK instead of automating Excel. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information about that.